# How to change colour of geom points using ggline

Tags: r, ggpubr

I would like to change the colour of the points on my chart

[image: ggline]

Presently they are all back points, I would like to change them to
instant = red, seconds = orange, minutes = yellow, hours = grey, days = black,
months = light green, years = green

Any ideas how to do this please?

```
       > dput(DF6)
    structure(list(as.numeric.Final_DF.age. = c(49, 47, 53, 45, 49, 
    51, 45, 45, 51, 43, 49, 51, 45, 49, 37, 45, 47, 59, 55, 39, 53, 
    51, 43, 51, 49, 47, 41, 53, 49, 39, 47, 51, 55, 43, 59, 49, 53, 
    57, 47, 41, 55, 47, 53, 41, 57, 43, 49, 57, 55, 61), Final_DF.pswd_length = c(8L, 
    4L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 13L, 7L, 
    9L, 8L, 6L, 13L, 12L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 8L, 10L, 
    10L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 14L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 11L, 
    4L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 12L), units_of_time = c(1, 1, 1, 7, 2, 2, 
    2, 3, 1, 7, 1, 2, 5, 2, 7, 6, 7, 1, 1, 7, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 7, 7, 
    4, 2, 7, 7, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 4, 1, 7, 7, 2, 1, 2, 7, 1, 4, 1, 1, 
    1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")

    ggline(DF6, x = "units_of_time", y = "as.numeric.Final_DF.age.", 
       add = c("mean_se", "jitter"), 
       order = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),
       ylab = "Age", xlab = "Time to crack") + scale_x_discrete(labels = c("instant", "seconds", "minutes", 
                                                                           "hours", "days", "months", "years")) +
  ggtitle("Time to crack password vs age")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign `color = "units_of_time"`  and use `scale_color_manual` to assign them colors as per your choice.

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

ggline(DF6, x = "units_of_time", y = "as.numeric.Final_DF.age.", 
       add = c("mean_se", "jitter"), 
       color =  "units_of_time",
       ylab = "Age", xlab = "Time to crack") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("instant", "seconds", "minutes", 
                              "hours", "days", "months", "years")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "grey", 
                                "black", "light green", "green")) + 
  ggtitle("Time to crack password vs age") + 
  guides(color=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks at the risk of asking another question is there a way to add a regression line to this plot?

Comment: @Marty, take a look at `geom_smooth()`.

Comment: @mhovd thanks how would I add this to my code?

Comment: @Marty Usually that would be as simple as adding `+ geom_smooth()` but that doesn't seem to work for this data.